# How to prompt error message when Wix installer failed

Tags: wix, installation

I am writing a wix project to deploy a website. 
I am using the `<iis:Certificate>` element.

If the `CertificatePath` is not correct, or the `PFXPassword` is not correct, the installation failed, but the installer didn't prompt error message. I could only find the error in the log file.

Is there any way to prompt the user about the installation failure if there any error happens?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way `iis:Certificate` element is implemented. Basically, it is a deferred custom action behind the scenes, which receives the information from another custom action and tries to do its job using the data it got.

All checks should go before the deferred part starts. I suspect that you pass the `CertificatePath` and `PFXPassword` as properties, and perhaps user enters the values. Anyway, you have to validate the values of those properties before letting it go further. If the value is not what you expect, you should prompt the user to fix it and don't let the installation flow to proceed without this.

It can be a custom action which is tied to the Next button on a wizard and doesn't let you move to the next dialog unless the properties are valid.